# Add columns to lists using cells with Background fill

Tags: python, openpyxl, python-pptx

Members of my organization would like to have the ability to color-code large spreadsheets of information which would then be pulled into a series list using (using Openpyxl) Python for insertion into PowerPoint (using Python-pptx). I've been able to get everything working except the Series, which needs a series name and the series data (organized in separate columns that may not be adjacent).

Here's what I have so far

```
        series_count = 2
        while series_count <= ws.max_column:
            for s in range(2, ws.max_column + 1):
                series_list = []                
                series_name = ws.cell(4, series_count).value
                for c in range(4, ws.max_row + 1):
                    cell = ws.cell(row = c, column = series_count)
                    if cell.value != series_name:
                        series_list.append(cell.value)
                chart_data.add_series(series_name, series_list, '0%') #Meant to take the series_name and series_list and create a chart using python-pptx
                series_count += 1
```

This only grabbing one series, and isn't inserting it into chart data. I'm not getting any exceptions, but when opening the PowerPoint document, there are only blank chart fields.

If the data is in adjacent columns, I can manually set the range, but this isn't feasible long term.

```
        series_count = 2
        while series_count <= ws.max_column:
            for s in range(2, ws.max_column + 1):
                series_list = []                
                series_name = ws.cell(4, series_count).value
                for c in range(4, ws.max_row + 1):
                    cell = ws.cell(row = c, column = series_count)
                    if cell.value != series_name:
                        series_list.append(cell.value)
                chart_data.add_series(series_name, series_list, '0%')
                series_count += 1
```

I'm a newbie, so I'm happy to consider other approaches to this issue that achieve the same result with minimal input from my even less technical colleagues. (They can manage color, but other formatting doesn't work well.)

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: What is `chart_data`? I don't recognise the method `add_series` from anything.

Comment: chart_data is an object in [python pptx](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/chart-data.html)

Comment: Your questions isn't clear. What is exactly wrong with series? Is there an exception raised or is the data not populating the chart in pptx export?

Comment: Apologies for any confusion. It's a complex problem. This code will grab one column as a series instead of multiple, and it is not delivered to chart_data (which is what creates the charts in the pptx export).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code seems to work for me.

```
    series_count = 2
    while series_count <= ws.max_column: #searches sheet for color-coded data and pulls it into series. 
        for s in range(2, ws.max_column + 1):
            series_list = []
            for c in range(4, ws.max_row + 1):
                cell = ws.cell(row = c, column = series_count)
                if cell.fill.start_color.index == 9:
                    series_list.append(cell.value)
                elif cell.fill.start_color.index == 8:
                    series_name = cell.value
                else:
                    pass
            if len(series_list) > 0:
                print "Adding", series_name, series_list
                chart_data.add_series(series_name, series_list, '0%')
            else:
                pass
            series_count += 1
```

Thanks for the assistance!